# Retrieving dynamic checkbox values and label from strongly typed view in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

EDIT: whoever fixed my question so the code displayed right, thank you! :)

I have a silly problem I really need som help with, after a whole day of googling I'm close to loosing my head!

I am working with the asp.net membership, and I want to be able to set roles on user once the web app is upp and running.

To implement this I am sending a model to a strongly typed view with a list of checkboxes, if the user is in one of the roles in the list the checkbox is checked. (this part works)

But I cant figure out how to return the checkbox values in the Edit method, as the model returns 'null' on the List-property.

I am sure I've missed something obvious here, and would be very happy for any help...

And how can I add code to this question? I cant get the formatting right...

**View**

```
@model Mvc4m.Models.UserRoles
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>UserRoles</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <h2> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" id="testar">

    @foreach (var model in Model.AllRolles)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => model.IsActive, model.Role)
        @Html.Label(model.Role)  
    }

    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsApproved)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsApproved)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsApproved)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public List<AllRolles> UserActiveRoles(string name)
{
    var list = new List<AllRolles>();

    foreach(var role in Roles.GetAllRoles())
    {
        var hej = new AllRolles()
                      {
                          Role = role,
                          IsActive = Roles.IsUserInRole(name,role)
                      };
        list.Add(hej);
    }
    return list;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
    var users = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                select new UserRoles()
                {
                    Name = u.UserName,
                    AllRolles = UserActiveRoles(u.UserName)
                };
    return View(users);
}

public ActionResult Edit(string name)
{
    var user = Membership.GetUser(name);
    var model = new UserRoles()
    {
        Name = user.UserName,
        AllRolles = UserActiveRoles(name)
    };
    return View(model);
}

//
// POST: /Admin/ManageUsers/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserRoles user)
{
    var name = user.Name;

    foreach (var role in user.AllRolles)
    {
        if (role.IsActive == true)
            Roles.AddUserToRole(name,role.Role);
        else 
            Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(name,role.Role);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Models**

```
public class UserRoles
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }

    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

    public List<AllRolles> AllRolles { get; set; }

}

namespace Mvc4m.Areas.Admin.Models
{
    public class AllRolles
    {
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can format any text as code by indenting it by 4 spaces - see [help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more details.

Comment: Instead of using a foreach can you use a for loop and in your CheckBoxFor use Models.AllRoles[i].IsActive.  That would then I believe output AllRoles[0].IsActive into the resultant view and then bind correctly on posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At UserRoles.cs**

Change

```
public List<AllRolles> AllRolles { get; set; }
```

to

```
public AllRolles[] AllRolles { get; set; }
```

**At Edit.cshtml**

Change

```
@foreach (var model in Model.AllRolles) 
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => model.IsActive, model.Role)
    @Html.Label(model.Role)  
}
```

to

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AllRolles.Length; i++) 
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => Model.AllRolles[i].IsActive)
    @Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.AllRolles[i].Role)
    @Html.Label(Model.AllRolles[i].Role)  
}
```

**At your controller**

Add `.ToArray()` after `UserActiveRoles(u.UserName)`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
    var users = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
            select new UserRoles()
            {
                Name = u.UserName,
                AllRolles = UserActiveRoles(u.UserName).ToArray()
            };
    return View(users);
}
```

**The problem**

You must show to the ModelBinder that you're sending a collection, instead of a bunch of parameters.

What's sent to the server?

> AllRolles[0].IsActive:false
>
> AllRolles[0].Role:Admin
>
> AllRolles[1].IsActive:false
>
> AllRolles[1].Role:User

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Kim! I decided to go with a drag and drop instead, but I like your solution and learned something new :) I'm sure others also appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple. You must give your checkboxes a name let's say myCheckboxes and you pass a int[] myCheckboxes to POST action. I've provided you a code sample:

In your view let's say you have

```
@foreach (var role in Model.AllRoles)
{
  <input type="checkbox" name="UserNotInRoles" value="@role.RoleId" checked/>@role.RoleName
  <br />
}

@foreach (var role in Model.UserRole)
{
  <input type="checkbox" name="UserInRoles" value="@role.RoleId" checked/>@role.RoleName    
  <br />
}
```

Now to post what user has checked/unchecked you use the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserRoleSaveVM saveRoles)
{ 

  if (saveRoles.UserNotInRoles != null)
  {                
     foreach (int roleID in saveRoles.UserNotInRoles)
     {
        //DO SOMETHING

     }
  }
```

where UserRoleSaveVM is

```
public class UserRoleSaveVM
{
  public int UserID { get; set; }
  public int[] UserInRoles { get; set; } //note that property name is the same as checkbox name
  public int[] UserNotInRoles{ get; set; } //note that property name is the same as checkbox name
}
```

Comment: How come the properties are int?

Comment: First to know is that when a check box is left unchecked it is not included in the POST collection so you'll get only the ones checked and to get a RoleId for the ones checked you use an int array int[] to store the values.

Comment: I think @Kim Tranjan answer suits my purpose better, but thank you for your answer, and time :)